# Divs stack next to each other not vertically: Abnormal behaviour?

Tags: html, css

So I expect these divs to behave block-like and just stack on top of each-other like nice little elements ... alas, tis not the case. I had this issue before and managed to fix it ... but I don't know how since it's happening again.

When I open the html file in chrome or firefox, the table (in it's own div) refuses to play nice and sit under the H1 (also in it's own div).

Note that the divs are to be centered as well and exist inside a container for that purpose. I am also trying to make this site HTML5 compliant. Seems a lot of useful things are not supported :/

Ye HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content" class="centered shadow">
  <div>
    <h1 class="reddy centered">Welcome to Riverbank Removals</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>  
    <table class="centered">
      <tr>
        <td class="items centered">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="table_head centered">Mon-Wed</td>
        <td class="table_head centered">Thurs-Fri</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="items centered">2 Men &amp; a Truck</td>
        <td class="price centered">Mon-Wed</td>
        <td class="price centered">Thurs-Fri</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>     
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Ye CSS:

```
body
  {
    background-image:url('bgd.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-color:#bb0000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }

#container
  {
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }


#content
  {
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#ffffff;    
  } 

.reddy
 {
   color:#bb0000;
 }

.price
 {
   position: relative;
   width:100px;
   font-size:16px;
   color:#bb0000;
 } 
.items
 {
   position: relative;
   width:100px;
   font-size:14px;
 }
.table_head
  {
    position: relative;
    width:50px;
    color:#bb0000;
    font-size:3;
  }
.menu
  {
    position:relative;
    width:280px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
  }

.centered
  { 
    /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;

    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;

    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;

    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-pack:center;
    box-align:center;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;       


  }
.shadow
  {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000000;
  }
```

Comment: Is this your complete CSS?

Comment: yes - totally.
The rest of the page is just the link to the CSS, in the head tags, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex.

```
direction: row;
```

You are trying to build rows, but you need a columns.

See the jsfiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/9VxtJ/3/

Also you should read this spec. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/

Comment: That's part of some cut'n'paste thing for making CSS center stuff... I have no idea what it's doing or why there is not a reliable, simple way to say "everything in here should be centered" ... like, I need the same functionality of the <center> in the main body as well as the align property of the <tr> tags.

Comment: jsfiddle is cool! Though the table isn't really tabling ... EDIT: It does when the centering thing is removed ...

Comment: Could you provide an example of how should this page look like ?
Also I see useless usage of .centered class inside of <td> tags.

Comment: I've updated jsfiddle link in the aswer to fix some <td> issues so you may check.

Comment: Thanks for this!  The centered class was supposed to do the job of the align property. Not sure how to do that in CSS since this method is non-functional. Also, I removed superfluous 'centered' assignments and that has fixed the issue ... Still not sure why though.

Comment: As for what it's supposed to look like, I don't really have anything I can point to easily. It's pretty basic stuff though - and it's working now. I would definitely be interested in the 'why' since I still don't get what broke and how to replicate the align thing now - the flex stuff seems to be wholly un-implemented?